# Resize event Qdialog

Tags: pyqt5

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo 2 frames dentro de un qdialog pero necesito que el frame tome como propiedades width() y height() el tamaño que vaya teniendo el qdialog .

Esto es lo que he intentado `self.frame.resize(self.QDialog.width(),self.height())`

pero no funciona aqui dejo mi codigo.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QDialog
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore


class Principal(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("12.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.frame.resize(self.QDialog.width(),self.height())
        self.frame_2.resize(self.frame.width()-900,self.frame.height())






app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
#p.resize(1000,600)
app.exec_()
```

Y mi codigo .ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>Dialog</class>
     <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>393</width>
        <height>300</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>Dialog</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>401</width>
         <height>301</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 211), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 221));</string>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>120</width>
          <height>301</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background:red;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <resources/>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
```

Comment: ¿te funciono mi respuesta?

Comment: @eyllanesc, funciono perfecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que el tamaño de los widgets dependan del padre debes usar layouts, en este caso debes colocar ambos frames en un QHBoxLayout. Asumiendo que en tu codigo tu deseas que el ancho del frame derecho sea de 900 entonces debes usar setFixedWidth(900).

***.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>604</width>
    <height>329</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
   <property name="spacing">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <item>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background:red;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 211), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 221));</string>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

***.py**

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Principal(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("12.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.frame_2.setFixedWidth(900)
        self.resize(1000, 600)
        self.dragPosition = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.center()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and not self.dragPosition.isNull():
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

    def center(self):
        qRect = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        print(centerPoint)
        qRect.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qRect.topLeft())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QDialog
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore

class Principal(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("12.ui",self)

        #self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        #self.frame.resize(self.QDialog.width(),self.height())
        self.frame.resize( 1000, 600 )
        self.frame_2.resize(self.frame.width()-900, self.frame.height())

app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
#p.resize(1000,600)
app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]